# Identifying the cause of a 301 redirect

Tags: redirect, moodle

I've got a Moodle website which has an unwanted 301 redirect on it.

I don't believe I was doing anything to the site at the time when the problem began, but the hosts are saying that the issue must lie somewhere in the site itself. Is there a way to scan to pinpoint where the redirect is coming from (i.e. site-side or server-side and, if the site, the cause)? I tried scanning with the Screaming Frog tool, but actually this has only confirmed that there's a 301 active, not where.

Does anyone know of any Moodle settings that could cause a redirect? I've been looking and can't see anything. I also can't understand why that setting would exist. I've now got access to the admin panel of the site, albeit not through the desired web address.

Below are the comments from the site hosts, which may help. Does it really sound like the redirect is on the site as is being suggested?

I'm at a bit of a loss. Any help would be gratefully received.

Thanks.

---

"Somewhere inside your site files or from the admin area of your Moodle website you have created a redirect rule for subdomain.domain.com to direct to domain.com. I have looked into this on your behalf to try and identify the redirect rule, however as we are not web developers I am afraid I did not found it.

However, to see if a redirect rule on your site indeed exists, I have edited the config.php file of your site. There I have set up for the URL of the website to be www.subdomain.domain.com instead of subdomain.domain.com.

Since now redirect was set up for www.subdomain.domain.com when accessing this URL (http://www.subdomain.domain.com/) your Moodle site loads. You can access your site via http://www.subdomain.domain.com/ and check through it's settings for any redirect rule you may have set up."

---